Как опубликовать приложение в Google Play?
Я публикую заново приложение на ГуглПлей. Старое ArtEcoFruit с публикации снял, новое назвал ArtEcoFruit+. Проект на FF тоже имеет новое название. Но при загрузке AAB выходит ошибка:

Какие могут быть варианты решения? Старое приложение рад бы удалить с ГуглПлей – не знаю как. Или переименовать? А что?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Проблема решена.
Надо изменить название этого пакета:


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
